# C++ : Read(Write) from(to) a file if provided otherwise fall back to std::cin (std::cout)

Tags: c++, file-io

I have this need. Read or write from/to file if provided otherwise fall back to good friends `std::cin` / `std::cout`, as in:

```cpp
// pseudo code for problem statement.

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  istream reader;
  ostrea writer;
  if (argc > 1) 
  {
    // we have path to our file in argv[] 
    reader = ifstream(infile);
    writer = ofstream(outfile);
  }
  else
  {
    reader = cin;
    writer = cout;
  }
 // rest of code
}
```

In essence,*even if my thinking is convoluted*, is there a way to achieve similar goals.
Thanks!

Env used: C++ 11, 14, 17.

EDIT #1:
To elaborate on the `if` condition, if the program is called as

```sh
$: driver "input_file.txt" "output_file.txt"
```

it should do IO from these files, on the contrary, if called so,

```sh
$: driver < "input_file.txt" > "output_file.txt"
```

it should use `std::cin` and `std::cout`

// End of Edit#1

I was reading through the reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf), and am thinking if this can help?

Comment: Make a function `read()`, overload it like so: `read(ifstream&, ofstream&); read(istream&, ostream&);` elaborate on the `if` condition you already proposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look toward the following approach:

```
void read_write(ifstream&, ofstream&);  // Overloaded reader-writer
void read_write(istream&, ostream&);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        auto infile = argv[1];
        auto outfile = argv[2]
        read_write(infile, outfile);
    } else read_write(cin, cout);
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: +1 this is more elegant and more testable than my version, but if you still need access to those readers or writers you may also consider pointers

Comment: @ben10 Here's just an outline, the rest will depend on other factors. If I would need further access to a reader/writer, I would introduce them as instances of classes.

Comment: Your thoughts on `rdbuf()`? 
Also, in case I have lot of variables to set to, I have to pass them to the function or make them globla (ew). Can this be mitigated in any way?

Comment: @RaviTiwari not sure I fully understood, but if I did, you can use pointers to those `std::ostream` and `std::istream` (writer and reader), as I mentioned, and pass them around. or as @rawrex said, add them to some class

Comment: @RaviTiwari it is too much of abstract terms to tell for sure what path to take. In general, if you have some data to manage that indicates a semantic coherency among its elements, it will be wise to pack it into a data structure (e.g. a `struct`). Also, consider introducing objects to manage all nuances internally, but providing concise and clear interface to be used in `main`.

Comment: @ben10 I can in your approach, as all variables will be local to main, but if I user overloading, then is there a way?

Comment: Well is there a way to use a polymorphic type to capture these, I am sure `istream` is base of `ifstream`. Any way thanks guys @rawrex, @ben10

Comment: std::istream is a common base of both std::cin and std::ifstream. I'm not sure, but I hope the example I posted as an answer kinda shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer to the baseclass of `std::ostream` or `std::istream`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  std::istream* reader;
  std::ostream* writer;
  bool deleteNeeded;
  if (argc > 1) 
  {
    // mark them for deletion, using a bool, for example
    deleteNeeded = true;
    // we have path to our file in argv[] 
    reader = new ifstream(infile);
    writer = new ofstream(outfile);
  }
  else
  {
    // mark for no deletion, setting the same bool
    deleteNeeded = false;

    reader = &std::cin;
    writer = &std::cout;
  }
  // rest of code
  if(deleteNeeded) 
  {
    delete reader; delete writer;
  }
}
```

Or use something like a reference than can be reassigned.

Comment: if you are going to do it this way at least use smart pointers

Comment: you'd need a custom deleter for std::cin then

Comment: "something like a reference that can be reassigned" ? Isnt that a pointer?

Comment: it is, or some fancy reference wrapper which is also a pointer, but with friendlier (?) syntax

Answer (score 1):

I dabbled with it post suggestions and thanks guys, this is what I came up with.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void solve(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) {
  int n;
  in >> n;
  out
    << n << " squared is " 
    << static_cast<uint64_t>(n)*n << " !" 
    << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::ofstream out(argv[2]);
    solve(in, out);
  } else {
    solve(std::cin, std::cout);
  } 
}

// call : ./driver in.txt out.txt
```